# Show NSWindow as a toolbar sheet

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsopenpanel, cocoa-sheet

How do you show a `NSWindow` from the toolbar, like the `NSOpenPanel` in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncheck *Visible At Launch* from the window properties in the NIB file and then use [beginSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsapplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/beginSheet%3amodalForWindow%3amodalDelegate%3adidEndSelector%3acontextInfo%3a):

```
[NSApp beginSheet:sheetWindow
           modalForWindow:mainWindow
           modalDelegate:self
           didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
           contextInfo:NULL];
```

Additionally, `NSSavePanel` provides [beginSheetModalForWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nssavepanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/beginSheetModalForWindow%3acompletionHandler%3a) as a convenience method:

```
[savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:mainWindow completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    if (result != NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) return;
    // Do something
}];
```